# Is this proof of the irrationality of the square root of $3$ valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, irrational-numbers

Assume that $\sqrt{3}=\frac{a}{b}$ where $\frac{a}{b}$ is in its simplest possible form. So $3=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$, hence $3b^2=a^2$. If $b$ is even then $a^2$ and $a$ are also even. That means they have a common factor of $2$. But this is impossible since $\frac{a}{b}$ is in its simplest form. So if $\frac{a}{b}$ does exist, $a$ and $b$ must both be odd. If $a=2k+1$ and $b=2m+1$ then $3=\frac{4k^2+4k+1}{4m^2+4m+1}$. After a few steps we get to $4(3m^2+3m)−4(k^2+k)=2$. If $3m^2+3m=c$ and $k^2+k=d$ then $4c−4d=2$ and so $4(c−d)=2$. This has no whole number solutions and that means that $a$ and $b$ are not even and not odd and that cannot be. So $\frac{a}{b}$ does not exist.

Comment: I can not write in LaTeX. Sorry.

Comment: x @waxo99: It would go quite a long way simply to enclose your formulas in `$...$` instead of `***...***`.

Comment: The proof is analogue to the case $\sqrt{2}$ , but not identical. To be more precise : Start showing $3|a$ and continue

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is correct, but as @Peter comments, it would be cleaner and faster to mimic the classic proof for $\sqrt{2}$: if $3b^2 = a^2$ then $3$ divides $a$, so $9$ divides $a^2$ so ...

Comment: @EthanBolker, cleaner and faster, perhaps, but I think the OP should be commended for coming up with their own, novel approach! I, for one, rather like it.

Comment: Mimicking the classic proof but with 3 is cleaner, less efficient (we have basic knowledge of even/odd numbers that, without unique prime factorization, we do not have of other primes), equally fast.  But it's mindless monkey work.  I'm impressed the OP took what could be a bad idea (could have gone nowhere), kept it from going off the rails, and found it worked!  And worked surprisingly efficiently!  Creative, intelligent, and elegant.  I give full marks.

Comment: @fleablood I agree. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine to me, except for a tiny detail: after saying that if $b$ is even, then $a$ must be even too, you should have added that the reverse is true: if $a$ is even, then $b$ must be even too.

And there's no need no introduce the numbers $c$ and $d$, though. You could just say that we can't have $4(3m^2+3m-k^2-k)=2$, since $4$ doesn't divide $2$.

Comment: There's one other minor error in the OP's proof:  It should be $4(k^2+k)-4(3m^2+3m)=2$, instead of $4(3m^2+3m)-4(k^2+k)$ on the left hand side.

Comment: @BarryCipra Good point!

Comment: Could you elaborate. I still can not find a mistake

Comment: @waxo99 \begin{align}3=\frac{4k^2+4k+1}{4m^2+4m+1}&\iff4(3m^2+3m)+3=4k^2+4k+1\\&\iff4(3m^2+3m)-4(k^2+k)=-2.\end{align}

Comment: I see thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Short version:**

$$c^2\bmod4=c\bmod2$$

so that with $a,b$ not both even,

$$(3a^2-b^2)\bmod4\ne0.$$

Comment: So is my proof valid or not ?

Comment: @waxo99 yep, you should recognize your argument.

Comment: $\equiv \mod n$ notation does a *lot* to change (usually for the better) notation that sometimes a argument is virtually unrecognizable.  Yes, OP, this is your argument and, yes, it is valid.